# Unable to make the cURL request using Windows Command prompt

Tags: windows, powershell, curl, command-line, windows-11

I read various articles and found that the latest versions of Windows support the `cURL` command via the `command prompt` right out of the box without any installation. So I am trying to make a simple `cURL` request to my local web server, but it is unable to make the request and get the response. It may be because the cURL request consists of the request body.

If I try to make the same request via `Windows Power Shell`, then it's also not working as expected. So I want to know why I cannot make the cURL request via Command Prompt and Power Shell.

Following is a sample cURL request that I am trying to make:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:9010/api/generatePersons?pretty=false' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "persons": [{
        "nodeId": 1,
        "eventType": "persons",
        "personID": false,
        "refPersons": [],
        "parent": {},
        "child": []
    }]
}'
```

Comment: Windows may now support `curl`, but `cmd` still doesn't support `sh` syntax. So you can't quote things with single quotes or use backslashes to continue commands. Shell quoting is hell in general; I don't know how you would write this in a comfortable way in `cmd`.

Comment: Why is this tagged PowerShell, when you say you want to do this in cmd.exe?  ''Jeroen Mostert', addresses the why. You are already saying this works for you in PS (thus not a PS code issue.), so, why not just use it?  There are ways to run multiline commands in cmd.exe. and there are docs and posts to show how.

Comment: @postanote My bad actually I have tried via `Command Prompt` and `Power Shell` as admin but in both its not working.

Comment: No worries, cmd.exe is not a dev environment, which is how you've structured your post. Though the Windows OS supports X or Y executables, does not mean you can structure it in a way Windows cannot process. Continuation line, CRLF, etc are environment specific. Cmd.exe means it must all be on one line, or you have a script file you call from X or Y shell. MS has specifically describes:[PowerShell- Running Executables - TechNet Articles - United States (English) - TechNet Wiki](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

***curl*** in PowerShell is not ***curl.exe***, it's alias for the cmdlet ***Invoke-WebRequest***.

```
Get-Alias -Name curl
# Results
<#
CommandType Name                      Version Source
----------- ----                      ------- ------
Alias       curl -> Invoke-WebRequest
#>
```

To use ***curl.exe*** in PS, you must fully qualify it using ***curl.exe***,...

```
Get-Command -Name curl.exe 
# Results
<#
CommandType Name     Version  Source                      
----------- ----     -------  ------                      
Application curl.exe 7.83.1.0 C:\Windows\system32\curl.exe
#>
```

...so that PS is not using Invoke-WebRequest.

```
Get-Command -Name curl
# Results
<#
CommandType Name                      Version Source
----------- ----                      ------- ------
Alias       curl -> Invoke-WebRequest
#>
```

As per my comment regarding multi-line cmd.exe code, for example:

> Multi-line string in command-line arguments
>
> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5bbaac03-52b2-48ed-a86b-4497665b6787/multiline-string-in-commandline-arguments?forum=vcgeneral
>
> In case of executables, consider _spawnl and _spawnv, where you can
> define the list of passed arguments. Example with a single multi-line
> argument:

```
_spawnl( _P_WAIT, "D:\\TestProgram.exe", "D:\\TestProgram.exe", "some\r\nargument", NULL);
```

> https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/dirs/Windows/System32/cmd_exe/line-continuation
>
> cmd.exe: line continuation
>
> A long command can be spread out over multiple lines if each line's
> last character is the caret (^) character. The following echo command
> prints the entire text on one single line:

```
echo ^
Hello world, ^
the number is ^
42.
```

Comment: So in other words the OP should stick to the CMD command line. Rather than PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Win 10 CMD command line answer.

```
curl -X 'POST' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "accept: application/json" http://localhost:9010/api/generatePersons?pretty=false' -d '{ "persons": [{ "nodeId": 1, "eventType": "persons", "personID": false, "refPersons": [], "parent": {}, "child": [] }]}'
```

The `?pretty=false` is not right.  A query string in the URL works for a GET or PUT request.  It is not kosher in a POST.  It does get submitted okay.

If it were a PHP API receiving this curl to get the `pretty`,use `$_GET[]` or `$_REQUEST[]`.

The issues you had were Microsoft induced.

- Do not enclose the URL in quotes
- Use double (not single) quotes for the headers

This should work for you:

```
curl -X 'POST' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "accept: application/json" http://localhost:9010/api/generatePersons?pretty=false -d '{ "persons": [{ "nodeId": 1, "eventType": "persons", "personID": false, "refPersons": [], "parent": {}, "child": [] }]}'
```